# How to layer multiple procedural texture in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm currently trying to achieve a few overlay of texture for my project, but I'm still new to blender and just have a basic understanding of node trees.

So, I followed a few tutorials and achieve the texture I want, but I'm not sure how can I overlay these textures together able to choose different color for each texture. The first image is the first texture I created and I want to overlay it with a grainy texture (like stucco) seen on the second image (first attempt) and the third image is a reference image of the grainy text, but probably smaller grain. the fourth image is the node I used for the first texture and the fifth image is the node for the second texture. If there any way to reduce the node complexity of the second texture, while achieving the same texture (it doesn't have to be procedural). Please let me know :)

Is it possible to have the option of choosing the color I want for each texture?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: I figure out the overlay texture, but I not sure how to make individual texture to have their own shade

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is clear, yet. Are you just wanting to combine bump maps, or are you wanting to vary color with each map, too? The screen-shots are too low-res to read.

Comment: Have you tried creating nodegroups for each texture then create a combining texture that uses the nodegroups and Mix Shader node?

Comment: Hi, I figured out last night of overlaying both textures by removing one of the texture and add the nodes for the procedural grain texture. I think only question now is how can I choose for each texture to have their own shade of color? I'll update the image